# NGINX+PHP-FPM ошибка 500

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

Всем привет, постоянно выскакивает ошибка 500, при этом php грузит почти на 100% процессор в логах пишет:

```
upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream
```

Мои конфиги:

```
# Server globals
user                    www-data;
worker_processes        auto;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;


# Worker config
events {
        worker_connections  2048;
        use                 epoll;
        multi_accept on;
}


http {
    # Main settings
    sendfile                        on;
    tcp_nopush                      on;
    tcp_nodelay                     on;
    client_header_timeout           1m;
    client_body_timeout             1m;
    client_header_buffer_size       2k;
    client_body_buffer_size         256k;
    client_max_body_size            256m;
    large_client_header_buffers     4   8k;
    send_timeout                    30;
    keepalive_timeout               60 60;
    reset_timedout_connection       on;
    server_tokens                   off;
    server_name_in_redirect         off;
    server_names_hash_max_size      512;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   512;


    # Log format
    log_format  main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
                        '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    log_format  bytes   '$body_bytes_sent';
    #access_log          /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    access_log off;


    # Mime settings
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;


    # Compression
    gzip                on;
    gzip_comp_level     9;
    gzip_min_length     512;
    gzip_buffers        8 64k;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml application/x-font-ttf font/opentype;
    gzip_proxied        any;


    # Proxy settings
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_header   Set-Cookie;
    proxy_connect_timeout   10m;
    proxy_send_timeout  10m;
    proxy_read_timeout  10m;
    proxy_buffers       32 4k;


    # Cloudflare https://www.cloudflare.com/ips
    set_real_ip_from   199.27.128.0/21;
    set_real_ip_from   173.245.48.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   103.21.244.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   103.22.200.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   103.31.4.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   141.101.64.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from   108.162.192.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from   190.93.240.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   188.114.96.0/20; 
    set_real_ip_from   197.234.240.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   198.41.128.0/17;
    set_real_ip_from   162.158.0.0/15;
    set_real_ip_from   104.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from   172.64.0.0/13;
    #set_real_ip_from   2400:cb00::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2606:4700::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2803:f800::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2405:b500::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2405:8100::/32;
    real_ip_header     CF-Connecting-IP;


    # Error pages
    error_page          403          /error/403.html;
    error_page          404          /error/404.html;
    error_page          502 503 504  /error/50x.html;


    # Cache
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=2 keys_zone=cache:10m inactive=60m max_size=512m;
    proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri $cookie_user";
    proxy_temp_path  /var/cache/nginx/temp;
    proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_502;
    proxy_cache_valid any 3d;

    map $http_cookie $no_cache {
        default 0;
        ~SESS 1;
        ~wordpress_logged_in 1;
    }


    # Wildcard include
    include             /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Помогите решить проблему. Заранее благодарен

Comment: Видимо что-то в скрипте долго работает (например большой sql запрос) и не успевает за минуту ответить nginx-у.

Comment: При выполнении какого именно запросы возникает 500 ошибка? Какую операцию вы при этом выполняете на сайте?